"is not null" check does not make C# believe that the value is actually not null
In below code, I have checked arethis.startingDate and this.startingDateTime not null, while C# still does not believe that these fields are not null and emits the errors I have mentioned in comments.
public class Task
{

  protected DateTime? startingDateTime;
  protected DateOnly? startingDate;
  protected DateTime? endingDateTime;
  protected DateOnly? endingDate;


  public bool areStartingAndEndingDatesAreDefinedAndEven
  {
    get
    {

      DateOnly startingDate;

      if (this.startingDate is not null)
      {
        // Cannot convert source type 'System.Nullable<System.DateOnly>' to target type 'System.DateOnly'
        startingDate = this.startingDate;
      } else if (this.startingDateTime is not null)
      {
        // Argument type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.DateTime'
        startingDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(this.startingDateTime);
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }

    }
  }

}

If is not null check does not proves that value is not null, what it the point of this functionality?

That's a type mismatch, not a nullability failure. Nullable<DateOnly> is not the same type as DateOnly. . BTW using the same name for a field and variable is a very bad idea.

@Panagiotis Nullable<DateOnly> is a value type.

You can use startingDate.Value to get the actual value or even better, use pattern matching eg if(this.startingDate is DateOnly d){ startingDate=d;}

@ProgrammingLlama sorry, I never mix up code like this so I always forget about Nullable

I'm hoping that eventually C# will allow "implicit Nullable.Valuedereferencing (i.e. anyNullablewill support implicit-conversion toTwhen the compiler is satisfied theNullableisnot null(i.e..HasValue`) - but right now it doesn't - so we gotta live with it.

What's the purpose of areStartingAndEndingDatesAreDefinedAndEven anyway? It won't compile because only one branch returns a value. I suspect all the code can be reduced into a simple switch expression

@PanagiotisKanavos As far as I can see maybe even return startingDate is not null || startingDateTime is not null; but I guess that's due to simplification.

The error complains about the type differences, not their nullability. DateOnly isn't the same type as Nullable<DateOnly> and there's no implicit conversion between them.
You can use .Value to get the actual value or use pattern matching:
if(this.startingDate is DateOnly d1)
{
    startingDate=d1;   
}
if(this.startingDateTime is DateTime d2)
{
    startingDate=DateOnly.FromDateTime(d2);   
}

or even
switch (this.startingDate,this.StartingDateTime)
{
    case ({} d1,_):
        startingDate=d1;
        break;
    case (_,{} d2):
        startingDate=DateOnly.FromDateTime(d2);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}

_ is a wildcard that matches any value.
A switch expression can be used as well :
var dateOnly=(this.startingDate,this.StartingDateTime) switch
{
    ({} d1,_)=>d1,
    (_,{} d2)=>DateOnly.FromDateTime(d2),
    _ => default;
}
...
return dateOnly==default;


I guess only the last one would compile in OP's context, though. A bool must be returned by that getter.

@Fildor the OP's code won't compile unless there's other code that returns a value. If the code was complete I suspect everything could be reduced to a single switch expression.

That's what made me suspicious, too. I don't really get the purpose of that property getter.

You should use the .Value property
public class Task
{
    protected DateTime? startingDateTime;
    protected DateOnly? startingDate;
    protected DateTime? endingDateTime;
    protected DateOnly? endingDate;

    public bool areStartingAndEndingDatesAreDefinedAndEven
    {
        get
        {
            DateOnly startingDate;

            if (this.startingDate is not null)
            {
                startingDate = this.startingDate.Value; // Here
            }
            else if (this.startingDateTime is not null)
            {
                startingDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(this.startingDateTime.Value); // And here too
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }           
        }
    }
}



Nit: Value is a property, not an operator.

@JonSkeet oops, my bad with the language

I think your confusion is justified. You are approaching the problem as if you dealt with nullable reference types with doing the checks for the c# compiler. The problem is that DateTime and DateOnly are value types.
Nullable value types predate nullable reference types and are implemented as real types, i.e. Nullable<T>. This demonstrates the difference.
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?) == typeof(int)); // false
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?) == typeof(Nullable<int>)); // true

// Error: CS8639 The typeof operator cannot be used on a nullable reference type
//Console.WriteLine(typeof(string) == typeof(string?));
string foo = "foo";
string? bar = "bar";
Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType() == bar.GetType());// true

The errors you receive are the same type of errors you would get had you done:
long veryBig = long.MaxValue;
int notAsBig = veryBig; // long might not fit in int
int foo = int.MaxValue;
long bar = foo; // int will always in long

and very similarly with nullable and nonnullable value types:
int? nullable = null;
int nonnullable = nullable; // what if null?
int foo = int.MaxValue;
int? nullable = foo; // okay -> c# compiler magic really

